# Relationship between entropy and ergodicity

Tags: ergodic-theory, entropy

Are there any direct connections between entropy and ergodicity? For example, does knowing that $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu,T)$ is ergodic help in computing the entropy?

I know that there are some *indirect* connections. For example, measure-theoretic entropy was developed as an isomorphism invariant to show that the $(p,1-p)$- and $(q,1-q)$-Bernoulli shifts are non-isomorphic when $p\neq q \neq 1-p$. But it seems merely coincidental that these shifts happen to be ergodic.

What I'm looking for is something like "If $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu,T)$ is ergodic then [something about entropy]." OR "If [something about entropy] then $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu,T)$ is ergodic."

**EDIT** Per the request in the comments, I'm interested in the [measure-theoretic entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure-preserving_dynamical_system#Measure-theoretic_entropy) of a measure-preserving dynamical system.

Comment: May you clearly and in detail describe what type of entropy you are talking about? And what type of system with regard to ergodicity?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi I added the **EDIT** per your request. Satisfactory?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it is along the lines you wished for but I'll comment anyhow:

The fact that the "entropy respect the ergodic decomposition" i.e. if 
$$ \mu =\int \mu_xd\nu(x)$$ 
implies
$$ h_\mu (T)=\int h_{\mu_x} (T) d\nu(x)$$

(for a reference see

http://www.math.ethz.ch/~einsiedl/Pisa-Ein-Lin.pdf

section 3.5)

have consequences more or less in the form that you want. For example that if there is a unique measure of maximal entropy then it is ergodic. This quite trivial fact if used a lot.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but very interesting. Thanks! Do you have a reference for this result? Does the result hold (at least when things are well-defined) more generally for any barycenter relationship?

Comment: I added a reference above. For your question maybe it is better to give a reference with proofs: check out section 5.5 of http://maths.dur.ac.uk/~tpcc68/entropy/Ch5November2011.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The *Shannon-McMillan-Breiman* $(SMB)$ theorem is along the lines "if $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu,T)$ is ergodic then (something about entropy)". It extends the "Asymptotic Equipartition Property" (which initially applies to i.i.d. processes) to hold for ergodic processes.
One version of the $SMB$ theorem is:
Let a stochastic process $\mathcal X=\{X_i,\;i=0,...\}$. Define the entropy (or entropy rate) of a stochastic process as $H(\mathcal X)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac 1n H(X_0,...X_n)$, where  $H(X_0,...X_n)$ is the joint entropy. Define also the conditional $k$th-order entropy as $H^k= H(X_k|X_{k-1},...X_0)$, and the conditional entropy rate $H_c(\mathcal X)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}H^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} H(X_n|X_{n-1},...X_0)$ . For completenes, for a random variable $Y, H(Y) = -E\log (Y) $ and we denote by $p(Y)$ its probability density.
Then **if the process is ergodic** we obtain that:

$$-\frac1n\log p(X_0,...,X_{n-1})\rightarrow H(\mathcal X) = H_c(\mathcal X) \;\text{with probability 1}$$

The proof is a bit long, and after all, this is not my result. Some references : 
**1)** Thomas & Cover (of course), "Elements of Information Theory" 2n ed. chapter 16 , **2)** Algoet, P. H., & Cover, T. M. (1988). A sandwich proof of the Shannon-McMillan-Breiman theorem. The annals of probability, 899-909.

Comment: I'm actually aware of this theorem and should've mentioned that I am. I wasn't considering it and am still deciding if it is what I had in mind. Nevertheless, you'll probably receive the bounty and autograph.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration. I acted on the information provided by the Question. Essentially you just revealed that your question was not after all ergodic (you just shifted the mean). As for the autograph, I will even let you choose the attire -I don't believe this qualifies as attempted bribery, eh?:)

Comment: What do you mean by "Essentially you just revealed that your question was not after all ergodic (you just shifted the mean)."?

Comment: Let's say there are $n$ "direct connections between entropy and ergodicity". The last two lines of the Question are the perfect description of a Uniform distribution: nothing is revealed about whether some of these $n$ connections may be stronger contestants for the bounty. So the question can be seen as an ergodic process of i.i.d uniform r.v's (the bounty hunters) whose realizations are the answers, each different answer having $\frac 1n$ probability of occurring (cont'd)...

Comment: (cont'd)  By "revealing" that the SMB theorem should not have been part of the eligible answers, you changed the cardinality of the support set of each r.v. from $n$ to $n-1$ _after_ the process has started to roll: you changed the distribution - hence the process was revealed not to be ergodic after all!

Comment: Lol. You's a silly dude!

Comment: If you provide an address, I'll mail you an autographed photo. My email address is firstnamelastname at gmail.

Comment: Going to the post office is not ergodic at all, and it has a lot of entropy. You can send it electronically - my e-mail is in my profile.

Comment: I don't see your email in your profile.

Answer (score 1):

In a very general and broad context, as the question is set, the answer is; that the so called *Fokker Planck equations* (FPE) and respective *Master equations* (ME) establish a deep relation between entropies and ergodicity (in some cases). The concrete formulations to be deducted then, are strongly dependent upon what type of system and what type entropy, you have in focus. For instance and as a very specfic view, in some stochastic dynamic systems a connector can be the Lyapunov Exponent being on one side related to entropy production (information gain) and on the other side to the stability characteristics that embody ergodicity aspects (such as when the FPE or ME translatable into higher order Markov Chains).

A good example how deep and diverse the answer to your question in this sense can be, motivates one to highlight the example of Phi-entropy inequalities and Fokker-Planck equations. Bolley and Gentil have an excellent excourse on this and the [part 2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.4478.pdf) of their 2010 article is such a formulation that would challenge perfectly your likely humoristic cliché of "is ergodic then [something about entropy]" vice versa.

Honestly said I think your question is sparkling out without required respect of research what is commonly expetced in this platform and at this level of theoretical elegance. Also dont understand why *we* around the world should be so much being beloved to have your autogram. Rather preferable you take more time to formulate such a question diligently and with some strong sensus of direction and insight. That would help us better being dedicated to rather specfic answers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sparkling out'?

Comment: Figuratively "raising inspirations".

Comment: And don't pretend that you don't want my autogram.